# Enabling PHP Pear on Linux

Tags: php, configuration, pear

I am having my PHP installation as "without pear" . I want to install PHP PEAR mail package so that i can send email from my application.

How can I enable the PHP Pear so that I can send Emails?
[image]

Comment: Ehm, just configure it again without `--without-pear`?

Comment: You can send emails without pear http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php

Comment: --without-pear compiled php without pear support..   its not simply that its disabled, its that it was without..  --with-pear=DIR 
would fix it..

Comment: I have now installed PHP PEAR in required directory now should i also download and install it's Mail package

Answer (score 4):

```
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ php go-pear.phar
```

see the manual http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

also in deb based os

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

Answer (score 1):

The "command configure" section of phpInfo shows the commands that where used during the compile of php.  In order to enable pear you would need to recompile PHP with pear support..

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.php

Answer (score 1):

In many distributions you can use the distributions package manager, for example

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

Answer (score 0):

PEAR is a collection of PHP classes, you don't have to "install" it. Simply download a package (which is normally one class and some helper classes) point (with `require_once`) your code to the main package class.

Comment: PEAR is also the name of the package installer and usually you what that to be installed properly